# fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: cross-compilation

I am trying to build Qt5 for the RPi board. The compilation worked fine, but I seem to be having problem with the install step. I get the following error:

```
fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I don't see the `bcm_host.h` in the `/opt/vc/include` folder of the RPi file system. Do I need to install a package?

I ran `rpi-update`. But I'm not sure how to include the directory path for `make`. So `make` keeps failing:

```
../../../../mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi-g++/qeglfshooks_pi.cpp:50:22: fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [.obj/release-shared/qeglfshooks_pi.o] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/gagan/src/rpi/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0-beta1/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
make[4]: *** [sub-eglfs-make_first] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/gagan/src/rpi/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0-beta1/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms'
make[3]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gagan/src/rpi/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0-beta1/qtbase/src/plugins'
make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gagan/src/rpi/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0-beta1/qtbase/src'
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gagan/src/rpi/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0-beta1/qtbase'
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: I thought those files were included with the standard Raspbian install and/or via rpi-update.  What system are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I don't think I ever ran rpi-update. I see the header file generated now.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't need to run rpi-update.  I use it to check to see if the latest kernel has broken any software.

Comment: Solved it by editing the make file of eglfs library to include the missing directories.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned elsewhere on Stack Overflow here: [Failed to cross compile Qt 5.6 on RPi 2 (fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40503/failed-to-cross-compile-qt-5-6-on-rpi-2-fatal-error-bcm-host-h-no-such-file-o) and here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=154749

You are missing the libraspberrypi-dev and kernel header apt packages, which you can install by running:

```
    sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi-dev raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

These packages are NOT included by default with a Raspbian lite distro.

Update: There are some references at https://forum.qt.io/topic/62264/failed-to-cross-compile-qt-5-6-on-rpi-2-fatal-error-bcm_host-h-no-such-file-or-directory/6 which indicate that updating your qmake.conf for the mkspec device will fix this error. I haven't tested that, but it seems reasonable to assume this will bypass whatever is causing the header to not be found if you've followed that other steps above.

Comment: Just for the people not to well-known with apt-get, the command above is not complete. It should be :

sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi-dev raspberrypi-kernel-headers

Comment: I'm running Buster Lite with latest updates and upgrades, and did apt-get install as described above. The first library was present but the second was not, so the latter was installed. However, I still get bcm_host.h not found when I do a make. I see that file in /opt/vc/include/ but it's the only file there, everything else is a folder. Is that file not being placed in the right place by apt-get ? If so, where should I put it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pulled your source code from [Raspberry Pi's kernel repository on GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/hardfp/opt), you'll want to copy the `vc` folder inside `firmware/hardfp/opt/` into your system's `/opt` directory. Replace files if `cp` or `mv` starts to moan.

Source: Experience

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions didn't work for me primarily because I didn't have the expected `/firmware/hardfp` directory at all. For me, what worked resulted from trial and error but worth noting for someone working with newer RPi4 Model B.

Kernel version:

```
        Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+ #1421 SMP Thu May 27 14:00:13 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

GPU firmware:

```
        /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version
        May 27 2021 14:02:15 
        Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
        version 7d9a298cda813f747b51fe17e1e417e7bf5ca94d (clean) (release) (start)
```

Solution:

1. Copy the bcm_host.h file from `/opt/vc/include` to `/usr/include`. This resulted in compilation error for more missing files like so:

```
        fatal error: interface/vmcs_host/vc_dispmanx.h: No such file or directory
         #include "interface/vmcs_host/vc_dispmanx.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       compilation terminated.
```

2. I looked in the `/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host` directory and found the file was present there. So, as suggested in other posts, I copied the entire contents of `/opt/vc/include` to `/usr/include`.

As a result, my program has compiled and I see errors that are related to the code itself.

Edit: Later, I found out that -lbcm_host library is not found by the linker as well. This resolved, as suggested on a thread in rpi forums, after I copied the contents of `/opt/vc/lib`, especially the `libbcm_host.so` into `/usr/lib`

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install libraspberrypi-dev` is enough to resolve the issue.