# Failed to cross compile Qt 5.6 on RPi 2 (fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory)

Tags: cross-compilation, qt

I tried to cross compile Qt 5.6 for RPi 2 by following the tutorial [RaspberryPi2EGLFS](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS), but I got this error:

```
qeglfsbrcmintegration.cpp:35:22: fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bcm_host.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make[6]: *** [.obj/qeglfsbrcmintegration.o] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_brcm'
make[5]: *** [sub-eglfs_brcm-make_first] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration'
make[4]: *** [sub-deviceintegration-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
make[3]: *** [sub-eglfs-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms'
make[2]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins'
make[1]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src'
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly states that the problem is that the compiler is missing `bcm_host.h`.  You should be able to fix this by installing `libraspberrypi-dev`.

The command below should fix it.

```
sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi-dev
```